# Openjson is not returning the json object when defining nvarchar(max), and working by nvarchar(4000)

Tags: t-sql, open-json

I try to extract a nested JSON from a JSON ([query]) 
if I do so, 
- with nvarchar(4000), it is working (unfortunatly some data are bigger)
- with nvarchar(max) as json, the field remains empty... why ??

--query=null :

```
SELECT 
visualContainers
     ,json1.[query]                                                

FROM [ReportServer_PBI].[Sections_RowSource] [sections]  
CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON(visualContainers)
WITH (
     [query]                                                     NVARCHAR(max)   '$.query'  as json
    ,[visualContainers.displayName]                              NVARCHAR(100)   '$.displayName' 
    ) as json1
```

--query contains data :

```
    SELECT 
visualContainers
     ,json1.[query]                                                

FROM [ReportServer_PBI].[Sections_RowSource] [sections]  
CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON(visualContainers)
WITH (
     [query]                                                     NVARCHAR(4000)   '$.query' 
    ,[visualContainers.displayName]                              NVARCHAR(100)   '$.displayName' 
    ) as json1
```

Comment: *Don't* use `nvarchar(max)` unless you really need to store more than 4K of Unicode data

Comment: thats the case... otherwise I wouldn't have a problem

Comment: A *lot* of people use `max` so they don't have to specify a size, not realizing it affects storage, indexing and performance.

Comment: That's not the only difference between the queries... The "not working" query use `as json`

Comment: yes thats normal when using nvarchar(max) in openjson

Comment: @OpenStove that should have nothing to do with the length of the `nvarchar` - and it's a difference between the statements. Try adding it to the working version or removing it from the not working version and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the contained JSON is improper.  JSON technically requires UTF8 encoding, so you could verify that.  You should also verify that the contained JSON is valid and is not fragmented (containing multiple JSON elements).

I use nvarchar(max) ... as json all the time and have no problems with it, so I doubt it relates to the length, but rather the fact that SQL Server probably validates and/or parses the text differently when using "as json"